# Can I use そうです (inference) in past?

Tags: grammar

> "It seems to me that he did not have the intention of following my advice"

Is it possible to say this sentence in Japanese using そうです, and if so, how?
I was aiming to use (よ)うとする constructions, but I encountered the problem that I don't know how to confer the temporal information.

> あの人は私のアドバイスに従おうとし...そうです。
>                                 しなかった => doesn't work because it would be hears
>                                 しなさ => lacks past tense

This is how I wanted to approach it, but I got the feeling that it doesn't work that way at all, because inference with そうです was introduced as a construction that is used for things I perceive through my 5 senses.

I think it's relatively easy to say it a bit differently with almost the same meaning, like:

> "あの人は私のアドバイスに従おうとしなかったと思います。"

But I still wonder whether there is a way to express this with a construction that bears the "It seems to me that..." semantics?

On a side note: Does そうだった work at all? To express "It seemed to me that..."?

Answer (score 5):

> "It seems to me that he did not have the intention of following my advice."
>
> Is it possible to say this sentence in Japanese using そうです, and if so, how?

No, it is not possible.  **Using 「そうです」 to talk about a past event will always make it a hearsay statement, not an inference one**.

Let us use a simple example sentence to examine this.

「雨{あめ}が降{ふ}**る**そうです。」 is **hearsay**.  "They say it is going to rain."

「雨が降っ**た**そうです。」 is **hearsay**.  "They say it rained."

「雨が降**り**そうです。」 is **inference**.  "It looks like it is going to rain."

「雨が降**り**そうだった。」 is **inference**.  "It looked like it was going to rain."

This last sentence should give you a clue about constructing an inference statement in the past tense, should it not?  To form an inference statement that fits your purpose this time, you could use:

> 従{したが}いそうになかった or　従いそうではなかった or 従わなさそうだった

All of the above are both grammatical and natural-sounding.  If your "base" phrase is 「そうです」 this time, then the last of the three 「なさそうだった」 would be the closest.

> 「あの人は私のアドバイスに従わなさ**そうだった**。」

There are multiple ways to say this as @s-k suggests, but let me repeat that you could ***not*** use 「そうです」 this time.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't use そうです in the sentence but I show some example It has something to do with that.

"It seems to me that he did not have the intention of following my advice"

=> あの人は私のアドバイスに従う気がなさそうだった。

=> あの人は私のアドバイスに従う気がなさそうでした。

=> あの人は私のアドバイスに従うつもりがなさそうだった。

=> あの人は私のアドバイスに従うつもりがなさそうでした。

These sentences have same meaning. "思います" is also okay though I prefer above expression.

Answer (score 1):

...し+そうです　=　...する+ようです/らしい

This would be, "It seems it probably will do ..."

Past tense: "It seems it probably would do ..."

...した+そうです ... した+ようです/らしい

Present/future negative form: "It seems it won't probably do ..."

...しなさ+そうです ...しない+ようです/らしい

Past Negative tense: "It seems it didn't probably do ..."

...しなさ+そうでした ...しない+ようでした

> "It seems to me that he did not have the intention of following my
>   advice"
>
> 彼は私のアドバイスに従わなさそうでした　(従わないようでした)