# そう with verbs in different forms as well as the differences with みたい

Tags: grammar, nuances, tense

Here are a couple of sentences:

1. 雨が降るそうです
2. 雨が降りそうです

Does 1 mean `I hear it will rain`, while 2 means `It seems it will rain?`?

And then, what about tenses?:

1. 雨が降ったそうです
2. ?

1 meaning `I heard it will rain`? There is no past masu stem so how would you create 2? Would 2 then just mean `It looked like it would rain`?

To add to my confusion, there is `みたい`. What is the difference between `verb masu stem + そう` and `plain verb + みたい`?

Comment: 雨が降ったそうです would be "I hear it rained" not "I heard it will rain". Be careful about which part is in the past. As for 2. this link is very related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/45100/7944

Answer (score 1):

when following what could be called 'sentence form',　そうだ　means I heard/people say that.

雨が降るそうだ - I heard it will rain

when following a verb's masu-stem or an adjective's stem (remove い or な as appropriate), そうだ means it looks like/seems

雨が降りそうだ - It looks like it will rain

Next you have みたい

みたい（だ） is a more casual version of よう（だ） and both work basically the same way:

It expresses

a) a likelihood of something (looks like/appears to be the case)
e.g. 木村さんは昨日お酒はを飲んだようだ・木村さんは昨日お酒を飲んだみたいだ　It seems that Mr Kimura dran sake yesterday

b) I likeness/similarity between one thing and another
e.g. この酒は水のようだ・この酒は水みたいだ　this sake i like water

The difference between みたい・よう　and そう (meaning looks like) is that：

そう is based on what the speaker sees or feels and there i less certainty than with よう which is also based on what the speaker sees/saw, but involves further reasoning on the part of the speaker to interpret the situation. There may be more reliable information involved here.

Basically, そう is a simple 'it looks like', where as よう is 'it seems to me, that...'

You may also find the expressions だろう/でしょう or らしい which can express similar ideas to the above.